# How to know whether launch image has been shown when applicationWillEnterForeground or applicationDidBecomeActive is called?

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, launch, default.png

I have added Default.png and Default@2x.png to a project. They are shown every time when the app starts. But when the app enters foreground from background, the launch image may be shown, and may not be shown. The showing or not showing may be related to the speed each time by which the app recovers.
The problem is, how do I know exactly whether the launch image will be shown, or has been shown each time?

Answer (score 0):

I think the launch image is not shown when the app "recovers", as you put it, but only if the app is actually restarted. You could easily check this by putting an `NSLog` statement into `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and observing when you see the image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sure the app "recover" is not actually restarted, but only goes back to front.
After I set the launch image, it shows almost every time in the simulator when the app goes from back to foreword. but in the real iPhone, it shows some times, though not so many as the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem and while googling I hit this question.

In my case it seems like the launch image is show if the app will recover in a different interface orientation than that one when it went to the background, even if changed to the upside down orientation.

You could compare the orientation before going to background with the orientation when returning. (use `applicationDidBecomeActive:`; `applicationWillEnterForeground:` is too early)